# Tikz Inside Table Cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

With my severely limited LaTeX knowledge, I am trying to modify an existing macro to produce bridge diagrams. Inserted is a basic output. I would like to center the Tikz-drawn square in the (almost) middle of the diagram. How can I do it?
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\@ifundefined{lettrine}{\usepackage{lettrine}}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
{\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}


\newcommand{\seatLabel}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

%%
\newlength{\br}
\setlength{\br}{18em}
%
\renewcommand{\c}{\(\clubsuit\)}
\renewcommand{\d}{\(\diamondsuit\)}
\newcommand{\h}{\(\heartsuit\)}
\newcommand{\s}{\(\spadesuit\)}

%
\newcommand{\hand}[4]{
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\br}%I chose \br=8em
 \begin{tabbing}
 %width of parbox depends on the parameters:
 %min{\br, max{string #1, ..., string #4}}
  \(\spadesuit\)  \= #1 \\
  \(\heartsuit\)  \> #2 \\
  \(\diamondsuit\)\> #3 \\
  \(\clubsuit\)   \> #4
 \end{tabbing}
 \end{minipage}     }%end \hand
%


%
\newcommand{\bd}[6]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ p{7em} p{7em} p{7em}}
#1 & #3 & #2\\
#4 & {\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}} & #5\\
   & #6 &
\end{tabular}
}%end \crdima
%


\newcommand{\phandcctest}[5]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0cm}%I chose \br=8em
%\begin{minipage}[t]{2.3cm}%I chose \br=8em
%\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.0cm}%I chose \br=8em
\begin{tabbing}
%width of parbox depends on the parameters:
%min{\br, max{string #1, ..., string #4}}
 #5 \= \\
\(\spadesuit\) \= #1 \\
\(\heartsuit\) \> #2 \\
\(\diamondsuit\)\> #3 \\
\(\clubsuit\) \> #4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%\hfill
\end{minipage} }%end \hand

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\cdot\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{A Switch in Time}


\author{Matthew Granovetter}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Introduction}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent \noun{The following deal} was reported by Eric Kokish in
\emph{Bridge Today} magazine, Nov/Dec 1993 issue.

\noindent \begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{18em}
\begin{small}
Santiago, Chile, Bermuda Bowl 1993, Semifinals\\
{Norway vs. Brazil}\\
\end{small}
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{center}\small{\textbf{VuGraph}}\\ \end{center}
\bd
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\br} \small Dealer: East\\N-S vulnerable   \end{minipage}}%
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\br} \small Lead: spade\\Contract: heart   \end{minipage}}%
{\phandcctest{QJ42}{\underline{7}}{AJ763}{843}{\seatLabel{Aa}}}%
{\phandcctest{K1085}{\underline{A}K543}{Q4}{AJ}{\seatLabel{Barbosa}}}%
{\phandcctest{976}{Q86\underline{2}}{K10952}{K}{\seatLabel {Comacho}}}%
{\phandcctest{A3}{J10\underline{9}}{8}{Q1097652}{\seatLabel{Groetheim}}}%
\\[1em]
\begin{minipage}[t]{\br}
\small{Closed Room Result: Five clubs doubled by the Brazilian South, down 1, +100 for Norway.}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{quote}``Five clubs doubled goes down only one in the closed room. The Brazilian
supporters are screaming with relief and delight. How can they possibly
lose now?''


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 62 you can replace `\begin{tabular}[t]{ p{7em} p{7em} p{7em}}` with `\begin{tabular}[t]{ m{7em} m{7em} m{7em}}`. And to draw a rectangle in tikz you can just do `\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);` ;)

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\@ifundefined{lettrine}{\usepackage{lettrine}}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
{\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}


\newcommand{\seatLabel}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

%%
\newlength{\br}
\setlength{\br}{18em}
%
\renewcommand{\c}{\(\clubsuit\)}
\renewcommand{\d}{\(\diamondsuit\)}
\newcommand{\h}{\(\heartsuit\)}
\newcommand{\s}{\(\spadesuit\)}

%
\newcommand{\hand}[4]{
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\br}%I chose \br=8em
 \begin{tabbing}
 %width of parbox depends on the parameters:
 %min{\br, max{string #1, ..., string #4}}
  \(\spadesuit\)  \= #1 \\
  \(\heartsuit\)  \> #2 \\
  \(\diamondsuit\)\> #3 \\
  \(\clubsuit\)   \> #4
 \end{tabbing}
 \end{minipage}     }%end \hand
%


%
\newcommand{\bd}[6]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{ m{7em} m{7em} m{7em}}
#1 & #3 & #2\\
#4 & {\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}} & #5\\
   & #6 &
\end{tabular}
}%end \crdima
%


\newcommand{\phandcctest}[5]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.0cm}%I chose \br=8em
%\begin{minipage}[t]{2.3cm}%I chose \br=8em
%\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.0cm}%I chose \br=8em
\begin{tabbing}
%width of parbox depends on the parameters:
%min{\br, max{string #1, ..., string #4}}
 #5 \= \\
\(\spadesuit\) \= #1 \\
\(\heartsuit\) \> #2 \\
\(\diamondsuit\)\> #3 \\
\(\clubsuit\) \> #4
\end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
%\hfill
\end{minipage} }%end \hand

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\cdot\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{A Switch in Time}


\author{Matthew Granovetter}

\maketitle

\chapter*{Introduction}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent \noun{The following deal} was reported by Eric Kokish in
\emph{Bridge Today} magazine, Nov/Dec 1993 issue.

\noindent \begin{quote}
\begin{minipage}{18em}
\begin{small}
Santiago, Chile, Bermuda Bowl 1993, Semifinals\\
{Norway vs. Brazil}\\
\end{small}
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{center}\small{\textbf{VuGraph}}\\ \end{center}
\bd
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\br} \small Dealer: East\\N-S vulnerable   \end{minipage}}%
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\br} \small Lead: spade\\Contract: heart   \end{minipage}}%
{\phandcctest{QJ42}{\underline{7}}{AJ763}{843}{\seatLabel{Aa}}}%
{\phandcctest{K1085}{\underline{A}K543}{Q4}{AJ}{\seatLabel{Barbosa}}}%
{\phandcctest{976}{Q86\underline{2}}{K10952}{K}{\seatLabel {Comacho}}}%
{\phandcctest{A3}{J10\underline{9}}{8}{Q1097652}{\seatLabel{Groetheim}}}%
\\[1em]
\begin{minipage}[t]{\br}
\small{Closed Room Result: Five clubs doubled by the Brazilian South, down 1, +100 for Norway.}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{quote}``Five clubs doubled goes down only one in the closed room. The Brazilian
supporters are screaming with relief and delight. How can they possibly
lose now?''


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kpym. One point: The text at the first and the third cell should be vertically-aligned to top. How can I fix that? Also, how do I, say, move the square a bit more down?

Comment: @blackened you are welcome. Then you have to apply another strategy : keep the `p` to align cells at the top, and put `\vspace` before your `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Line 64 becomes `#4 & \vspace{1mm}{\begin{tikzpicture}`. You can manually adjust the `1mm`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at CTAN? There is a package called [`bridge`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bridge). Of course!

In fact it is a `.tex` file from 1991 which still uses `\documentstyle` (LaTeX 2.09). I've downloaded in my computer, changed `\documentstyle` to `\documentclass`, compiled with pdflatex and got

[image]

It looks like what you want. The figure is done with command

```
\begin{quote}
\crdima{N/None}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\br}
     Play:\\demo
  \end{minipage}}%
  {\hand{J74}{AJ}{QJT2}{Q874}}%
  {\hand{A3}{K76}{963}{KJ952}}%
  {\hand{K86}{T9542}{874}{T3}}%
  {\hand{QT952}{Q83}{AK5}{A6}}%
\end{quote}
```

which is defined in this document.

Comment: Thank you, Ignasi. Yes, that package was my starting point. Didn't fancy the rectangle in that package (and some other bits), that's why I'm continuously modifying it.