# How to adjust tikz picture so it fits to current size of a table cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I already tried solutions given in 2 similar questions: [TikZ Picture in Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152067/tikz-picture-in-table) and [Tikz Inside Table Cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217545/tikz-inside-table-cell) but they do not seem to work for me.

Below I give MWE and what I tried. I have a tikz picture inside a long table cell. I want it to automatically fit into the width of the cell.

When using an actual image and `\includegraphics` I would adjust the `width` manually to make it fit. But do not know how to do it for a tikz pic.

I am also using the "m" option for the cell, to make the image align OK with text in other cells.  But if I remove the "m" option and put back the "p" option on that cell, it makes no difference for the tikz scaling.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\ifdefined\HCode %Michal's driver for tex4ht use
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi    
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} %for the m option on cells   
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{.25in}|p{1in}|m{1.4in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.35in}|p{0.4in}|p{0.35in}|p{.2in}|}\hline
A&
Heat PDE in bar (1D)&
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\coordinate[label =above:$0$,   label =below:{$u=0$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label =above:$\pi$, label =below:{$u_x=0$}] (B) at (4,0);

\draw (A) -- node[above] {$u_t = k u_{xx} $}  node[below] {$f(x)$} ++ (B);

\node at (A)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\node at (B)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{}; 
%\addvmargin{1mm}   %has no effect if I uncomment it
\end{tikzpicture} 

(Haberman 2.3.3 (a))&
B&0.415&C&2.376&Yes\\\hline
\end{longtable}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to scale the tikz pic size to automatically fit into a table cell?

Compiled using `lualatex foo2.tex` using  Using TL 2019 on linux.

```
lualatex foo2.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)
 restricted system commands enabled.
```

Comment: If you use `\coordinate[label =above:$\pi$, label =below:{$u_x=0$}] (B) at (0.95in,0);` it almost fits.

Comment: @marmot thanks. But this is just one example. I plan to draw many such small diagrams and each will be little different, and I do not want to do manual adjustments to each one image code. When using `\includegraphics` I will set  the `width` to that of the cell width, whatever it is. (in this case, it is `1.4in`) but this could change. Is there similar option in tikz?

Comment: There is adjustbox but the issue is that it rescales the fonts, too. One can rewrite your tikzpicture rather easily in such a way that it is 1.2in wide, but this is not a general solution.

Comment: Scaling fonts is OK. That what happens when changing width using `\includegraphics` I basically want everything in the tikz to scale so it fits. It is ok if it get small to read.

Comment: Then you could load `adjustbox` and wrap your `tikzpicture` into `\adjustbox{max width=1.2in}{ ... }`. This works fine as long as you do not want to remember the coordinates and use them elsewhere.

Comment: @marmot wow! that is a great solution. Yes, this is what I want. Please feel free to post it as answer and will be happy to accept it. I did not know I could do this. It  is easy for me to change the width parameter to make it same as cell width for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that this must be some sort of a duplicate answer but anyway `adjustbox` is made for such things. Note that if you do that, you should not use `remember picture` and try to access the coordinates from "outside". And `\adjustbox` comes with its own mechanisms of vertical or horizontal alignment, but not using any seems to work fine. In any case, you should not expect `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` to work properly here either. In a way, the `tikzpicture` will behave as a graphics included with `\includegraphics`, but if that's what you want then `adjustbox` seems to be the right tool.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\ifdefined\HCode %Michal's driver for tex4ht use
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi    
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} %for the m option on cells  
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{.25in}|p{1in}|m{1.4in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.35in}|p{0.4in}|p{0.35in}|p{.2in}|}\hline
A&
Heat PDE in bar (1D)&
\adjustbox{max width=1.2in}{\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label =above:$0$,   label =below:{$u=0$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label =above:$\pi$, label =below:{$u_x=0$}] (B) at (0.95in,0);

\draw (A) -- node[above] {$u_t = k u_{xx} $}  node[below] {$f(x)$} ++ (B);

\node at (A)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\node at (B)[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{}; 
%\addvmargin{1mm}   %has no effect if I uncomment it
\end{tikzpicture}} 

(Haberman 2.3.3 (a))&
B&0.415&C&2.376&Yes\\\hline
\end{longtable}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Addendum: as [mentioned above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488857/how-to-adjust-tikz-picture-so-it-fits-to-current-size-of-a-table-cell#comment1234315_488857) you can rewrite the `tikzpicture` in such a way that it has the desired width. However, this is not a general solution. I am adding this merely to say that there is no need to introduce ad hoc distances like `0.6\linewidth`, but you do have to look at the picture and find out which are the left-most and right-most nodes (`u=0` and `u_x=0` in this case). One can then start with those "extremal nodes", use appropriate anchors (along with `outer sep=0pt`) to place them such that the picture has the right width, and then add the rest relative to them.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}    
\ifdefined\HCode %Michal's driver for tex4ht use
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi    
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} %for the m option on cells  
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{.25in}|p{1in}|m{1.4in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.35in}|p{0.4in}|p{0.35in}|p{.2in}|}\hline
A&
Heat PDE in bar (1D)&
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),nodes={outer xsep=0pt}]
\node[anchor=west] (A0) at (0,0) {$u=0$};
\node[anchor=east] (B0) at (\linewidth,0) {$u_x=0$};
\node[label=above:$0$] (A) at ([yshift=0.2ex]A0.north) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\node[label =above:$\pi$] (B) at (B0|-A) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{}; 
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$u_t = k u_{xx} $}  node[below] {$f(x)$} ++ (B);
\end{tikzpicture} 

(Haberman 2.3.3 (a))&
B&0.415&C&2.376&Yes\\\hline
\end{longtable}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

make image width(determined with line length + width of nodes) dependent from cell width:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\ifdefined\HCode %Michal's driver for tex4ht use
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                positioning,
                quotes}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\begin{longtable}{|m{0.25in}|m{1in}|m{1.5in}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}
                  |m{0.35in}|m{0.35in}|m{0.35in}|m{.25in}|}\hline
A   &   Heat PDE in bar (1D)
    &   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.base),
        every node/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
                dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt}
                            ]
        \node (A) [dot,label=$0$,   label=below:{$u=0$}]    {};
        \node (B) [dot,label=$\pi$, label=below:{$u_x=0$},
                   right=0.6\linewidth of A]               {}; % <---
        \draw   (A) to ["$u_t=k u_{xx}$","$f(x)$" '](B);
        \end{tikzpicture}

(Haberman 2.3.3 (a))
    &   B   &   0.415   &   C   &   2.376   &   Yes     \\\
    hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]